# How to set aside certain numeric values of x with ggplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a continuous scale including some values which codify different categories of missing (for example `998,999`), and I want to make a plot excluding these numeric missing values.

Since the values are together, I can use `xlim` each time, but since it determines the domain of the plot I have to change the values for each different case.

Then, I ask for a solution. I think in two possibilities.

- Is it possible to put non-determining limits to the x-values? I mean, if I give 990 as a maximum limit, but the maximum value that appears is 100, the plot should show an x-range till approximately 100, not 990, as `xlim` does.
- Is there an opposite function to `xlim`?, meaning that the range determined by the limits (or a discrete set of values given) won't be included in the x-axis.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to exclude these values in the plot, either before or during the ggplot call.

#### MWE

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create data with overflowing data
mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars2[5:15, 'mpg'] <- 998

# Full plot
mtcars2 %>% ggplot() +
   geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = disp))
```

#### Filtering before plot

```
mtcars2 %>% 
   filter(mpg < 250) %>% 
   ggplot() +
   geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = disp))
```

#### Filtering during plot

```
mtcars2 %>% 
   ggplot() +
   geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = disp), data = . %>% filter(mpg < 250))
```

Comment: I was looking for something like your `Filtering during plot` option. It works. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! It's an almost undocumented feature, but it's often really useful to overlay multiple layers in the same plot (e.g. labelling outliers).

Answer (score 1):

I would filter those missing values from the original dataset:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(cat = rep(LETTERS[1:4], 3),
                 values = sample(10, 12, replace = TRUE)
)
# Add missing values
df$values[c(1,5,10)] <- 999
df$values[c(2,7)] <- 998

invalid_values <- c(998, 999)

library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  filter(!values %in% invalid_values) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(cat, values))
```

[image]

Alternatively, if that's not possible for some reason, you can define a scale transformation:

```r
df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(cat, values)) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::trans_new('remove_invalid',
                                               transform = function(d) {d <- if_else(d %in% invalid_values, NA_real_, d)},
                                               inverse = function(d) {if_else(is.na(d), 999, d)}
                                               )
                     )
#> Warning: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis
#> Warning: Removed 5 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-09 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).